# Data structures in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I have to implement a program in C, and I need a data structure to efficiently manage some data.   I was wondering what would be the best way to do this. Any suggestions or pointers are appreciated. Thanks!

A simplified example of the kind of data to be stored is as follows. Suppose that for every subject taught at the school, we need to keep track of the number of students whose grades fall within a range. Lets assume that the range size is user defined and is 10, so the ranges will be 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, and so on. The start of ranges will be 1, 10, 20 and so on. Thus, the data looks like:

```
Subject Id,  start of range of student grades, #students who got grades within this range. 
   1              30                                 1
                  80                                 5
                  90                                 6

   2              50                                 3                  
                  60                                 6

   3              40                                 1
                  70                                 5
```

Notice that all the ranges are distinct i.e. no two subjects can have the same start range.

Note: This isnt homework as someone pointed out, I really need this to keep track of filenames , their access counts by different users (# accesses), and within certain timeslots (ranges).

Comment: This smells like homework ...

Comment: No, its not really though I can see that the example data is simplified and may seem like it. I really need to keep track of filenames (subject id -> file id), their access counts by different users (# accesses), and within certain timeslots (ranges). Besides, I am just looking for hints and suggestions, I can write the code.

Comment: How do you define "efficient"? Fast inserts? Fast lookup by Subject ID? Do you want to know the subjects with 3 students in the 30-40 range? There are a lot of ways to store data, choosing one depends on what you plan to do with it afterward...

Comment: Your best bet is probably a relational database then and some nice access scripts for it. Why C?

Comment: Fast inserts will be nice, though I really need fast lookups by subject idea, followed by start range. Most common queries are: 1. given a subject id, what would be the total #entries in all ranges.2. Given a range, what subject id would this belong to? (I actually will have unique ranges per subject id in my real data), 3. What would be the max/min range per subject id

Comment: Dear Mimisbrunnr, I really need a light-weight data structure in c which is fast, I am not going to need the entire functionality of an RDBMS (joins, etc) for any complex queries, just a few specific queries.

Comment: How sparse is the data? (How many Subject/Range pairs will actually have no Students in them?)

Comment: A subject can have no range, though the probability of this isnt very high, I can have 1000 subjects with 2-3 having no ranges. Most will have at least one range If they have an entry for range, they will always  have students in them.

Comment: @lostinpointers: I mean, with regard to my solution, how many 0's will be in the matrix? And how many Subjects and distinct Ranges are there?

Comment: There will hardly be any, < 1%. There can be about a 100,000 subjects with about 1000 ranges, if not more.

Answer (score 1):

How about a matrix (2D array) sized as Number of Subjects by Number of Ranges. Each element will hold the number of students for a particular Subject in a particular Range.

You need to do the mapping of Range start to Column in the matrix separately.

Update:

Since you say you have 100M entries that adds up to a lot of memory.
Consider adding an extra layer of indirection and dividing the large matrix into many smaller ones.
(You'll need a mapping from an Subject to an integer row index and from a Range to a column index. Subjects 1 through N and Ranges 1 through M go to Matrix1, N+1 to 2N and M+1 to 2M go to Matrix2 and so on.)

You'll need to do a lot of tests and determine the N and M that provide the best performance. (Make a program that runs a large number of "common" operations and times them. Graph the execution time, divided per operation type, as a function of N and M.)
Since they'll depend on processor caches and other parameters it's unlikely the values will be the same on different systems so they should be configurable on the end program.

Edit:

My solution would create a matrix like this one below(based on the data in your post). You might need to copy-paste it to view at full width.

```
Subject\Range
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   6   
2   0   0   0   0   0   3   6   0   0   0   
3   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   5   0   0
```

There are a lot of 0's in it so it's not efficient memory-wise. It should have decent performance (you might want to check the option of dividing the matrix into smaller ones and testing the performance of those implementations.)

To find the used ranges for a given Subject you need to examine the row corresponding to the Subject, any cell > 0 means it's column matches an used range.
To find the subjects for a given range, examine the column for the appropriate range.

Comment: One subject can have more than one range, so the 2-d array wont really work..

Comment: @lostinpointers: Yes, it will. Each range is a separate column in the matrix. This assumes the ranges are mostly common to all the Subjects.

Comment: Performance is priority, memory not as much,  since this will be a parallel application, so its fine to use the same structure.  Now I get it, you are right, it will work, though the 2d matrix will be sparse since there will be a single mapping between a range number and the subject.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of subjects isn't too large, then this should work:

```
#define NSUBJECTS ...
#define NRANGES 10
struct data {
    int    subj_id[NRANGES];
    int    nstudents[NSUBJECTS][NRANGES];
}
```

Initialize the values with, say, `-1` to indicate non-availability.

Comment: number of subjects can be large, up to several thousands.